# Boolean Logic: How to chain if else correctly in one statement (insteand two nested if statements)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic, boolean-logic

I built a date filter with the variable "from" and "to".

I discovered, that it matters, if I put a if else into another if else (which I guess is not true, but is now my case).

### While this does not work ...

```
if (
  (from !== null || to !== null) &&
  (...some more if elses)
) {
  some code
}
```

### ... this works ...

```
if ((from !== null || to !== null)) {
  if (
    some more if elses
  ) {
  some code
}
```

... why?

### Full example (if the following if else outknock the previous):

```
if (from !== null || to !== null) {
  if (
    (from && to === null && dataItemDate >= from) ||
    (to && from === null && dataItemDate <= to) ||
    (from && to && dataItemDate >= from && dataItemDate <= to)
  ) {
    matchAllFilters = true;
  } else {
    matchAllFilters = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: A nested `if` is the same as using `&&`. If it doesn't work the same, this might be an error when writing the conditions or a quirk of the language you use.

Comment: Great. At least it makes sense ... It is written in JavaScript and the full code is added in description. Do I do there something wrong?

Comment: What values *exactly* give you different results? [Here is what I tried](https://jsbin.com/zibifis/1/edit?js,console) and it seems like these behave the same.

Comment: @Ehrlich_Bachman please provide a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).